# How do I get the duration information of currently working internet connection using C#?

Tags: c#, windows

When we look at the general information of the current internet connection in Windows we can easily find the duration. Does anyone know how to retrieve this information pragmatically using C# or C/C++ in Windows?

[image: Duration of internet connection]

Thanks a lot

Aaron

Answer (score 1):

First Add reference from Network List Manager 1.0 Type Library

```
        var manager = new NetworkListManager();
        var connectedNetworks = manager.GetNetworks(NLM_ENUM_NETWORK.NLM_ENUM_NETWORK_CONNECTED).Cast<INetwork>();
        foreach (var network in connectedNetworks)
        {
            if (network.IsConnected)
            {
              network.GetTimeCreatedAndConnected(out uint _, out uint _, out uint 
              pdwLowDateTimeConnected, out uint pdwHighDateTimeConnected);

              DateTime networkConnectedTime = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc((long) 
            (((ulong)pdwHighDateTimeConnected << 32) | pdwLowDateTimeConnected));

            TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(networkConnectedTime);

            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + network.GetName() + "  Duration : {0} day(s) {1}:{2}:{3}", diff.Days, diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, diff.Seconds);
                 }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use NetworkInformation;

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
```

add event method method for `NetworkAvailabilityChanged`

```
NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler(NetworkConnectivityStatusChanged);    

void NetworkConnectivityStatusChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
{
        ONLINE = e.IsAvailable;
}
```

I guess I misunderstand the question, but you can add your own timer in `Changed` event and when it goes offline you can reset it

Comment: It seems to me that there is no way of retrieving this duration information directly? I thought whatever shows on the general tab can be gotten easily using exiting API.