# How to obtain IP Address from Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface Powershell and average system throughput?

Tags: powershell

I noticed that under in the **Status** window for a network interface in **Network and Sharing Center**, it shows how many bytes have been sent and received, as well as the duration.

By knowing the duration, I can calculate the average bandwidth used by the system.

Also, since I am using `Windows 10`, I can go to **Network & Internet** and in the **Status** tab it lists  the data usage over the past 30 days. This is less ideal since it doesn't seem to differentiate between upload and download.

I would like to know the average throughput of several `Windows 10` systems by using a `Powershell` script to automatically obtain those values. How can I do this?

The command:

```
Get-NetAdapterStatistics
```

returns the number of bytes sent and received, but duration is not there, so I can't calculate the average rate.

The command:

```
$Tcpip_NI = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface -computername "LocalHost"
$Tcpip_NI | Select BytesReceivedPersec, BytesSentPersec, BytesTotalPersec, Name;
```

returns additional information which seems to be about throughput.

**Edit** I'm pretty sure these don't return the values I'm after, at least on my system. I got like 3.3 Gbps when my internet connection at most is 100Mbps. I'm pretty sure LAN traffic is included in this value, but still, I would not reach a continuous average of 3.3 Gbps on my system. Anyways, just realized this, but I'll leave what I have below.

However, I would need to know the IP address of each of the interfaces, associated with the `Name`s.

I tried using the following command but the `InterfaceAlias` is different from the `Name`s listed from the above command. So I cannot make the correlation between the output of the above command and below command in terms of name and IP address.

```
Get-NetIPAddress |Select IPAddress, InterfaceAlias
```

Okay, I'll test in a moment, but I think this command should show the correlation between `Name` and `InterfaceDescription`:

```
Get-NetAdapter
```

Comment: This has me intrigued so I looked into it. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64799023/14903754) with the answer you're looking for, the only issue is that it's in C# and it's missing how to initialize NLM. So I found this [post](https://rcmtech.wordpress.com/2016/11/24/network-list-manager-in-powershell/) which shows you just that, so the only issue I'm running into is passing the proper values to `.GetTimeCreatedAndConnected()`; [ref](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetwork-gettimecreatedandconnected). Just not sure how to go about it